# Watson assistant preview link is not working

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation, watson-assistant-solutions

The preview link created in IBM Watson Assistant is not working 
https://assistant-chat-eu-gb.watsonplatform.net/web/public/3d262aef-38e5-476e-87f8-6c0177f1c72a

But works perfectly with the Slack. Can anyone help me to sort out this issue?

Comment: Add more context to your question. Right now I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: In Watson assistant, there is an option for Preview Link Integration. On saving it, we get a preview URL... Using that URL we can chat with the assistant Bot.  Example https://assistant-chat-eu-gb.watsonplatform.net/web/public/3d262aef-38e5-476e-87f8-6c0177f1c72a     But on going this link its generate an error "assistant-chat-eu-gb.watsonplatform.net’s server IP address could not be found.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN"

Comment: @Captureca Did you create the Watson Assistant service in London region?

Comment: Issue Solved changed the url by eu-gb to us-south

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have able to resolve the issue by simply changing the URL by eu-gb to us-south.
Old URL with issue

```
https://assistant-chat-eu-gb.watsonplatform.net/web/public/3d262aef-38e5-476e-87f8-6c0177f1c72a
```

New URL

```
https://assistant-chat-us-south.watsonplatform.net/web/public/3d262aef-38e5-476e-87f8-6c0177f1c72a
```

Please the discussion in IBM Community [https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/479867/watson-assistant-visit-url-or-preview-link-is-not.html](http://IBM%20Community)